# Magento import un-assigning products in configurable products

Tags: magento, import, upload, configurable-product

We use Magento CE v1.8 I've heard that if you have configurable products and have products assigned to them correctly, these can be unassigned when you try and import an updated CSV. The suggestion was that if you upload a new csv every time your configurable products will always have products un-assigned to them is this true? I cannot find any evidence of it anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard of this kind of issue. If you are uploading Simple Products only the Simple Products' information will be updated. It's tough to update Configurable Product details (including which products are assigned to them) but it can be done relatively hassle-free using  and the Configurable Item Processor plugin.

Just uploading a CSV via Dataflow Profiles or Import *shouldn't* unassign simple products from configurable products if the data in your CSV is just a list of Simple Products.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I didn't think Magento wipes out existing product data unless you select it to.